# Moving Ratings from EE1 to EE3 site

Tags: import, solspace-rating

I'm currently rebuilding an EE1 site in EE3. The EE1 site is using Rating v2.3.4 and the new EE3 site is using Rating v4.0.4.

What's the best method for migrating ratings between the two sites? Rating v2.3.4 has a rating export utility, with which I created a CSV file of all of the ratings on EE1 site. However, I can't find any method for importing those ratings into EE3 using Rating v4.0.4.

Should I just look into importing the ratings straight into the EE3's DB (after, of course, making sure all of the related entries exist, IDs match up, etc.)? Or is there a different method?

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, the best way to go about this would be to do this in stages. I'd make a clone of the original site. Then upgrade it to EE2 and Rating 3.x. Then upgrade that site to EE3 and Rating 4.x. You could either then work with that site for the new build, or copy over those updated database tables to the new site.

But definitely don't attempt to copy over EE1 Rating 2.x database tables over to EE3 Rating 4.x database, and there is not Import feature (the export CSV feature is only there for customers that wish to copy their rating data into a spreadsheet for internal usage, etc). :)

Comment: That does seem pretty sensible. :) Unfortunately, it's a bit too late in the development process to do the EE1 -> EE2 -> EE3 upgrade path. The site's already been rebuilt in EE3, weblog/channel entries have been imported, etc.

Any other options in that case?

Comment: This aspect of the site update should have been considered earlier on. :/  Unfortunately I don't think there's any other way to go about this, other than custom building some sort of migration utility, but that could be time consuming and/or expensive. And to confirm, you don't have the old EE1 site in any way to do the steps I mentioned above, just for the Rating data?